# installing pip is not work and any reaction

Tags: python, installation, cmd, pip

I want to install pip.
I run "python get-pip.py" in command prompt window and I did not see any reaction in window. pip didn't install. and don't show any error message.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are not sure if you have pip, try installing a module.

If you are sure that you dont have pip, try installing some IDEs like PyCharm or Anaconda. Other than that I'm sure I never ran any code or downloaded something specific for installing pip.